# Execute function when modal is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and using this to show a modal after a click event:

`$('#make_selects_modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');`

I need to be able to execute a function (called `pickClient`) when this is shown. I tried something like this, but it doesn't work. Not sure of the correct syntax.

```
$('#make_selects_modal').appendTo("body").modal('show').pickClient();
```

Answer (score 4):

When the modal is visible, an event called `shown.bs.model` is fired.

You can use

```
$('#make_selects_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', pickClient);
```

[Modal event docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Answer (score 2):

From the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) you can use events for this, specifically in your case the `shown.bs.modal` event:

```
$('#make_selects_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    pickClient();
})
```